All Lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the form $\{A + tv \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \}$
i want to show that all lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the form $g =\{A + tv  \mid t \in \mathbb{R}  \}$. (Note: Everything here refers to the euclidean distance)
We defined lines as subsets of a metric space that are isometric to $\mathbb{R}$.
So to prove that the lines have the form of g, I need to find an Isometry $f: g \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.
From intuition I would say that the map: $A+tv \mapsto |t||v|$ would be a good candidate.
But I am not sure about the point where I need to show that this map preserves distances.
We need to show:
$$d(A,B)=d(f(A),f(B))$$
Without loss of generality I fix $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $B$ is another point on $g$ with $B=A+tv$. ($A=(x_1,y_1)$ a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$  and $v=(v_1,w_1))$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$)
$$d(A,B)=d(A,A+tv)=\sqrt{(x_1+tv_1-x_1)^2+(y_1+tw_1-y_1)^2}=|t|\sqrt{v_1^2+w_1^2}=|t||v|$$ (|v| denotes the euclidean norm of the vector $v$)
and $$d(f(A),f(B))=d(0,|t||v|)=|t||v|.$$
But is this even correct?
I'd be glad If someone could help me out :)
Thanks in advance!

You need to be precise about what $A,v$ are. In particular, is $v$ a vector? What is its norm?

Hello, thank you for the comment, I edited the question.

I was going to say the same thing, but instead suggest that the map be $A + tv \to t / |v|$. But even that is problematic -- -it assumes that you know $A, t,$ and $v$, and those are the things you're supposed to be showing exist!

Deliberately partial answer, guiding you towards a complete answer, I hope
You're about 80% of the way there. I suggest you take the isometry in the other direction -- a map
$$
q: \mathbb R \to g
$$
that preserves distances. You can then define $A = q(0)$, and $v = q(1) - q(0)$ (which is nonzero because ... ). And you might as well define $B = q(1)$ just to have a second point to talk about. Note that the distance from $A$ to $B$ is $1$. (Why? Again, you get to fill in here.)
Now what remains to show is that for any $t$, the point $A + tv$ is in the image of $q$. That will presumably involve the triangle inequality in some way. In particular, you very much expect that $A + tv$ is just $q(t)$, right? But who's to say that the image of $q$ isn't a nice arc of a circle that just happens to pass through the two points $A$ and $B$?
Let's look at $q(2)$. What you know about it is that

Its distance from $A$ is 2. (Why?)
Its distance from $B$ is 1. (Why?)

What do these two things tell you geometrically? Can you generalize beyond "t = 2"?
Post-comment additions
If we call $q(2)$ by the name $C$, then we can show that the angle $BAC$ has cosine 1, so it's an angle of $0$. I guess that's one way to express it.
Another is to say that the first of the two conditions says the point is on a circle $C_1$ of radius $2$; the other says it's on a circle of radius 1 that passes through the center of $C_1$, and therefore meets $C_1$ in a single point, which lies on the ray from the center of $C_1$ through the center of the smaller circle. That was the idea I had in my head, anyhow.
What about your proof? Let me walk through it with comments.

i want to show that all lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the form $g =\{A + tv  \mid t \in \mathbb{R}  \}$. (Note: Everything here refers to the euclidean distance)
We defined lines as subsets of a metric space that are isometric to
$\mathbb{R}$.  So to prove that the lines have the form of g, I need
to find an Isometry $f: g \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. From intuition I
would say that the map: $A+tv \mapsto |t||v|$ would be a good
candidate.

Right here there's a problem: what you seem to be saying is, "Suppose I have a line in the $A + tv$ form; can I find an isometry to $\mathbb R$?" but that's the wrong question, because you don't have $A$ or $v$ when you're given the thing called a line in your definition. What you have is a set $g$ (that's a terrible choice for a name, by the way, because it makes it look like a function, analogous to $f$, but that's a mere editorial point). And you know that there's an isometry between $g$ and the real line. What you need to show is that there's a point $A$ in the plane and a vector $v$ in the plane with the property that $g = \{ A + tv \mid t \in 
\mathbb R \}$.
One challenge here is that if $g$ has that form, then there are millions of choices for $A$ and $v$ -- $A$ could be any point of the line, and $v$ could be a vector of any length that 'points along the line.' So if you come up with a pair $(A, v)$, I could equally well offer up $(A + 2.6v, -3v)$ and be equally correct. Problems that have multiple solutions are often harder than those with just one solution. Anyhow, onwards...

But I am not sure about the point where I need to show that this map
preserves distances.

You don't need to show the map preserves distance -- that's a given.

We need to show:
$$d(A,B)=d(f(A),f(B))$$

This is again an editorial point, but "A" already has a special meaning in what you've written so far, while here you're using "A" and "B" as generic points of your line. That's valid, but confusing to the reader. It's much kinder to say something like "We need to show that for $X, Y \in g,$, we have $d(X, Y) = d(f(X), f(Y))$" Of course, as I already noted, that's not what you need to show.
Now onwards, to what you actually started writing:

Without loss of generality I fix $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$ \ldots

Um...you probably want to fix $A \in g$, not just any old point in the plane!

\ldots  and $B$ is
another point on $g$ with $B=A+tv$. \ldots

You've introduced $v$ here without explanation. I think what you really meant to say was "Given a line $g$, let $A$ and $B$ be two distinct points of the line, and $v = B - A$. We'll aim to show that $g = \{A + tv \mid t \in \mathbb R \}$.

($A=(x_1,y_1)$ a point in
$\mathbb{R}^2$  and $v=(v_1,w_1))$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$)

I like this naming of parts in general; it helps keep the reader grounded in actual coordinates that you'll be using in a moment.

$$d(A,B)=d(A,A+tv)=\sqrt{(x_1+tv_1-x_1)^2+(y_1+tw_1-y_1)^2}=|t|\sqrt{v_1^2+w_1^2}=|t||v|$$
(|v| denotes the euclidean norm of the vector $v$)

The sentence above is fine.

and $$d(f(A),f(B))=d(0,|t||v|)=|t||v|.$$

I don't understand where the fragment above comes from.
I find, when writing things like this, that going back to my old days in geometry class helps. Doing proofs there, we took a sheet of lined paper and drew a vertical line down the middle. The left column was labeled "Statement" and the right was labeled "Reason". A typical entry would be
S5: Triangles ABC and DEF are congruent | R5: S1 - S4, SAS congruence

where S1 through S4 said things like "AB = DE" with "Given" as a reason. You can do the same thing here, and it's really helpful. When you get everything worked out, you may discover that some re-ordering is useful ("I should name the coordinates before I use them!"), and then you can convert your two-column proof into something more easily readable. But if there's a statement that doesn't have a corresponding reason...don't start converting yet!

But is this even correct?

As I mentioned in my very first paragraph, you were working backwards. What you were given to work with was a set $g$ and an isometry $f$ between $g$ and $\mathbb R$; what you needed to do was find a point $A$ and a vector $v$ such that $g = \{A + tv \mid t \in \mathbb R\}$, and then prove the equality of those two sets.
The one useful thing here is that you get to choose the direction of the isometry, because if $f$ is an isometry, so is $f^{-1}$. In sketching my (partial) answer, I chose to make $f$ go in the opposite direction from you. Why? Because with my $f$, I know a lot about the domain --- the reals are my bread and butter! --- so it's easy to talk about things like $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. If we go the other direction, I don't even know how many points the set $g$ contains...maybe a priori it's the empty set or something! (OK, that's not possible, because $f$ is a bijection, but even before you assign a name to a point of $g$, you need to note that $g$ is nonempty, so it's a lot harder to work with an isometry that goes the other direction.

Thank you very much! Is it correct that the image of 2 under q lies on the line g because from the triangle equality and the fact that the distance from A to q(2) is 2 and B from q(2) is 1 and A to B is 1 that: 2  $\leq$ 1+1 = 2. From that we can conclude that A,B,q(2) are on the same line

And I have general question regarding your answer. Is my proof of isometry in my question above correct and your answer is an add-on to complete my proof or is my proof wrong?

See post-comment additions.
